# Retrieving info from barcode? (made with ZXing library)

Tags: android, barcode, zxing

I'm creating an app for those who have specific dietary needs which will have the ability to scan bar codes and tell the user as much info as possible kind of link the question below: 
[Android : Get data from a barcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48550107/android-get-data-from-a-barcode)
I have built my scanner in android studio using ZXing library, and the scanner function is working, but i would like it to display info about the food scanned. I have been looking into this for quite a while and have found no solution as the barcode is just numbers and the info on it is in the supermarket's etc. database. So my question is, is it possible for the app to do this? Or should I create a database with different foods and link it somehow to the app? Thank you.

Comment: You don't need to create any database, there are a lot of resources online also databases, look here http://openfoodfacts.org/ , http://www.upcdatabase.com , http://www.yoopsie.com/
When you've scanned your bar code, you need to make a query into these database and retrieve and show data in your app

Comment: Thanks! so I need to link one of the above to my app. Should I add it to the dependencies in the gradle build file? (sorry i'm new) this is what I have in my dependencies right now.

Comment: dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])   
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'   
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'       
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'   
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'   
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'   
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.0'   
    implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9'
}

Comment: You need to make a query to one of these database and retrieve data, checkout Volley library, also Retrofit is very good. These libraries make an http request from android, and then you need to make a query and retrieve data. Checkout online for a tutorial.

Comment: Thank you I will check out the libraries, your references to the online resources were very helpful, Open food facts has 789121 products from various countries! Just to be clear (as i'm still relatively new to coding terminology and want to make sure I fully understand what you are trying to say), i'm going to check online for a tutorial to "make query to database and retrieve info"? to allow the results of the scan to show more info about the product scanned (for now the barcode scanner only displays the barcode number when scanned). Thank you very much for your help, it is much appreciated.

Comment: okay so i'm back and i'm sorry I still cannot get the app working. I connected it to volley which was simple enough as all I had to do was add it in my dependencies. Its the connecting to Open Food Facts that I can't get right. I downloaded their files from GitHub to compare my code to theirs and there's literally so much of a difference. I got rid of the code I thought was making the problems and i'm back and square one. I have another problem that has arised now but I will leave that for another topic. I looked into tutorials for making queries & retrieving data but they are all using mySQL.

Comment: Any tips on what to do? Sorry for the trouble again.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I've figured that what i'm looking to do is possible. I couldn't get the app to retrieve data from a database (as the user arst3k mentioned above), I found something helpful when looking through Open Food Facts 
https://world.openfoodfacts.org/data
Here is where I got the idea to go to their Github, and compare my files to theirs to see what I was missing, didn't work out well though as there was so much they had that I didn't. But, I saw that they also have other options (i'm still not sure if these options are for users to integrate into projects) they have an option to download CSV files. I downloaded CVS files for products I needed, and looked online for tutorials on how to link the file to my android studio project so when something is scanned, it will look in the CVS file to see if the product is there and if so, should then display info on that product. So far all I've found is how to add to CSV files and not how to retrieve from them. I'm still trying to find a way to do the above.

The point is, the answer is this is possible. And also, if anyone's got any more ideas, let me know thanks.